# Adding textview margin/padding inside alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i'm trying to add margin for my textview inside alertdialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()); 
builder.setTitle(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationTitle());
final TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
tv.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );   
tv.setText(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationMessage());
builder.setView(tv);
```

I'm trying to change my script to this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setTitle(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationTitle());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
                final TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
                tv.setLayoutParams(params);
                tv.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
                tv.setText(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationMessage());
                builder.setView(tv);
```

but still no help, so how can i add margin to my textview ?

Comment: Is this a custom dialog box? Can you share the xml file for the same?

Comment: i don't use custom layout for this dialog

Comment: The AlertDialog is difficult to customize. Have a look at creating a custom DialogFragment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. As you are adding a textView so you don't need `tv.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setTitle((notificationList.get(position).getNotificationTitle());
    final TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.height = 100;
    layoutParams.width = FrameLayout.MarginLayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.setMargins(50, 20, 50, 10);
    tv.setText(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationMessage());
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    builder.setView(tv);
    builder.create().show();
    tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

You can change margin in `layoutParams.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` as your need.
The `mContext` is a context of an activity in which you are using the alert dialog. So make sure that the activity should have theme Theme.AppCompat. Or you can change the style for app.

eg:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
    }
}
```

now onward you can use `mContext` as a context in the current activity or subsequent fragments in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()); 
builder.setTitle(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationTitle());
final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
ll.removeAllViews();
final TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
tv.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );   
tv.setText(notificationList.get(position).getNotificationMessage());


LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
 tv.setLayoutParams(params);
ll.addView(tv);
builder.setView(ll);
```

Comment: i get this `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
`

Comment: Please try edited once and let me its woking or not.